# write my own delta compression?

Tags: c, compression

Is there any reason that I absolutely should not write my own delta compression library (in C)? I'm working on proprietary project and cannot include any GPL'd code (and most others in fact).
Being not an expert in binary data compression, I'm wondering if I do go this way, where should I start? All data involved is highly patterned binary with roughly the same length (~100K).
Sorry for the rather vague question.. Thanks in advance for any insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zlib](http://zlib.net/) is freely available and reusable, even in proprietary software. ([Here is the license.](http://zlib.net/zlib_license.html)) There is no reason to try and recreate it.